# I can't uninstall Git

Tags: windows, uninstall, git

I was researching Git so I downloaded the Windows version to test it out on a repository on GitHub.  After about 30 minutes I couldn't work out how to use it, so I decided I probably wouldn't need a distributed repository as our projects aren't that big and went back to what I know - SVN.

(I thought) I uninstalled all the Git related stuff I'd put on my PC, but have now got an irritating problem where if I open any folders I get an error message saying:

> Hello
>
> [ERROR] Could not find git path

As you can imagine, this is a real pain, does anyone have any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/getting-started/uninstalling-github-desktop/

Answer (score 19):

This would happen because

Uninstall was unable to delete the file "C:\Program Files\Git\git-cheetah\git_shell_ext.dll"

The correct fix would be to unregister the dll and delete it

1. open the Command Prompt window
2. execute > regsvr32 -s -u git_shell_ext.dll
3. delete "C:\Program Files\Git\git-cheetah\git_shell_ext.dll"

If that does not work here's an ugly workaround:

1. Open "Task Manager" and go to Processes
2. Find explorer.exe and click end process
3. Choose File > Run in "Task Manager" and type 'cmd' and click OK to open "Command Prompt" and cd to "C:\Program Files\Git\git-cheetah"
4. Delete git_shell_ext.dll
5. Restart

be sure to clean-up after reboot, remove "Git" folder from "C:\Program Files"

Comment: thanks so much.. had the same problem. was driving me nuts

Comment: It's easier to open a command prompt first before ending explorer process because when you end explorer, taskbar and start menu will be gone.

Comment: I had this happen after _installing_ TortoiseGIT for the first time. In my case, running `regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Git\git-cheetah\git_shell_ext.dll"` got things working.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to have a look at this, it shows what shell extensions are installed and can help to remove problematic items:

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html

Incidentally, you should have given GIT a chance - it takes a while, but the payback is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

How To Fix Error Could Not find The Git Path ?

1. Restart Your System And Press <kbd>F8</kbd> Before Booting To Windows.
2. Select Safe Mode
3. select Administrator User
4. go to c://program Files/
5. Delete Git Folder

And Then Restart

I would appreciate feedback if this solved your problem

Comment: I've fixed up your answer for you. While I'm not going to fault your language use, on SU, we tend to keep the answers to the point (that is so say, its unnecessary to have a greeting in front), and we really would appreciate it if you didn't randomly use capital letters where they don't belong. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem I needed to stop the service and its dependence:

1. Start>>Run>>cmd>>tasklist /M >> c:\Documents and Settings\"Your user"\Desktop\tasklist.txt
2. Open the generated file on your Desktop
3. Press Crtl+F
4. Find for git
5. The process need to be closed is "explorer"
6. Stop "explorer" process
7. Enter the folder tha contains it
8. delete Delete git_shell_ext.dll
9. Reboot the system