# problem uninstalling GIT on windows

Tags: git

so, 
after uninstalling git, i started to receive countless popups "[hello] could not find git path" messages, uninstalling and reinstalling git didn't do anything.. finally i found [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/126385/i-cant-uninstall-git/143830#143830) and that helped to make them go away.

now, after it has been uninstalled and manually expunged, i still get this message:

"**gitdll.dll was not found. reinstalling the application may fix this problem**"

this message pops up about 5 time per click (or even getting explorer window focus).. rendering windows unusable..

i would like to get rid of git once and for all.. any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download [AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx), open it and accept the EULA.
2. Wait for it to scan everything...
3. Use CTRL+F and F3 to search and disable GIT-related entries.
4. Just disable the mark or if you are pretty sure you could hit DEL but you can't recover that.
5. Reboot and the errors should be gone as Explorer doesn't look for the dll anymore.