# "[error] cannot find git path" when trying to run program

Tags: windows, git

> **[error] cannot find git path**

I bought a laptop (used) and it works fine except for this problem - when I go to *Start* and *Programs* and try to open ANY program it gives me this error. This is a blanket issue - does it on ALL programs from the Start menu.

I am running Windows XP Home on a HP mini.

I don't know what `git` even is so I really need some help.

Comment: actually - it gives me this error on everything - even *if* it still does the function...but it does NOT ever do function from start.

Comment: [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)) is a version control system. Might be that the previous owner had it installed and somehow messed up the system. Why are you actually using a pre-owned system and don't reinstall?

Comment: did you instll Git or TortoiseGit? Where do you downloaded from?

Answer (score 1):

You bought a laptop and you are using the system without formatting and reinstalling the OS? First do that, you might have other issues, viruses, back doors from the seller etc.

Since this is happening for all programs and not only for Git and you don't even know / care about Git, I again stress that you format and install your OS again.

That said, do "echo %PATH%" on command line ( winkey + R -> cmd ) and paste the output in the question. Will help in finding out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

When you install msysgit on windows, you get an integration option which will allow you to use it from the "Run" menu.

I've never installed it with that option, but it seems like that might cause it to make a fuss whenever it can't find the git binaries in your PATH.

I think, and don't quote me on this, that there's some weird hacking to make git transparently available through the windows command prompt, but you might try looking for installed git (msysgit?) and uninstalling it?  Or if you want to add it to your path, in Control Panel > Advanced > Environment Variables, it'll mightlook something like:

```
GIT   C:\path\to\git.exe
```

[problem uninstalling GIT on windows](https://superuser.com/questions/157358/problem-uninstalling-git-on-windows) gives instructions if uninstalling it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The main answer here ([I can't uninstall Git](https://superuser.com/questions/126385/i-cant-uninstall-git)) will solve your issue. Basically, you have to unregister this dll C:\Program Files\Git\git-cheetah\git_shell_ext.dll

```
1. open Windows Command Prompt 
2. regsvr32 -s -u git_shell_ext.dll
```