# How can I stop Git cheetah showing the [ERROR] Could not find git path message?

Tags: windows-xp, git

I have installed Git on windows XP, along with the Git cheetah explorer shell extension.
However, as I open each shell window I see an error dialog pop up with title `"Hello"`, and the text:

```
"[ERROR] Could not find git path"
```

Git is definitely installed, but how can I point git-cheetah at it?

Installer version: Git-1.7.3.1-preview20101002.exe

OS: Windows XP SP 3, 32 Bit.

Note: I am aware that there are questions with similar search terms relating to **uninstalling** git, but that is not what I want to do.

Things I have tried:

- Adding the git/bin directory into the system path environment variable and logging out/back in. It has propagated, but the error did not go away.

Comment: Probably a silly question, but is the error correct - ie, does Git Cheetah work anyway?

Answer (score 2):

I started getting similar behavior.  On a hunch, I followed [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/126385/i-cant-uninstall-git).  However, this question is about uninstalling.  We only want to fix our existing broken install.

1. Find your Git for Windows install path.  Mine is: `C:\Program Files\Git`
2. If necessary, gain local admin rights.  (This is necessary at my office.)
3. Start command prompt (cmd.exe)
4. Run this command: `regsvr32.exe "C:\Program Files\Git\git-cheetah\git_shell_ext.dll"`

It should fix the problem.